# How to concatenate large dataset into dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas

So I am working with a fairly substantial CSV dataset that has couple hundred megabytes. I have managed to read in the data in chunks (~100 rows). 
How do i then elegantly convert those chunks into a dataframe and apply the describe function to it?
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you need [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) of `TextFileReader` object what is output of [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) if parameter `chunksize` with [`describe`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html):

```
df = pd.concat([x for x in pd.read_csv('filename', chunksize=1000)], ignore_index=True)
df = df.describe()
print (df)
```

Comment: That is so beautiful.
When should I use concat vs append?

Comment: I think with `list comprehension` is better use `concat`.